# Writing good object-oriented code under AnyEvent

Tags: perl, asynchronous, anyevent

We're building a large application with complex logic, which is composed of modules. I used to build larger scale methods of simpler methods, for instance,

```
# fig. 1   
package Foo;
sub highlevel {
    my ($self, $user, $event) = @_;
    my $session = $self->get_session($user);
    my $result = $self->do_stuff($session, $event);
    $self->save_session($session);
    return $result;
};
```

(this is simplified of course). Results are returned, exceptions are thrown, everyone's happy.

Now, we're making a move to AnyEvent. My module is NOT the uppermost level, so I can't do just

```
# fig. 2
my $cv = AnyEvent->condvar;
# do stuff
return $cv->recv;
```

Most AE modules I've seen so far work like this:

```
# fig. 3
$module->do_stuff( $input, 
    on_success => sub { ... }, 
    on_error => sub { ... }
);
```

So I'm done rewriting the lower-level methods and tried to proceed with highlevel() and...

```
# fig. 4
package Foo;
sub highlevel {
    my ($self, $user, $event, %callbacks) = @_;
    my $done = $callbacks{on_success};
    my $error = $callbacks{on_error};
    $self->get_session( $user,
        on_error => $error,
        on_success => sub {
             my $session = shift;
             $self->do_stuff( $session, $event,
                  on_error => $error,
                  on_success => sub { 
                       my $result = shift;
                       $self->save_session( $session,
                            or_error => $error,
                            on_success => sub { $done->($result); }
                       );
                  }
              );
          }
     );
 };
```

Not exactly beautiful. I call it "the Infinite ladder".

Now the next thing I could come up with was an ad-hoc state machine where highlevel() is broken up into _highlevel_stage1(), _highlevel_stage2() etc. But that doesn't satisfy me as well (it's unmaintainable, and thinking of good names instead of stageXX gives me headache).

We're already looking into a full-blown state machine to drive the whole app, but having to add a transition for *every* interaction looks a bit too generous to me.

So the question is: What are the best practices for writing modules that implement business logic (fig. 1) for running within an AnyEvent app (fig. 3)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to encapsulate it in a Future object using the [`Future`](https://metacpan.org/release/Future) module. That adds syntactical sugar to make this cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

Executive Summary: you either want inversion of control (threads with Coro that block) or a state machine.

You could use Coro, which can convert the infinite ladder into linear code (by inversion of control), e.g. using Coro::rouse_cb/rouse_wait, or some of the Coro::AnyEvent functions:

```
   do_sth cb => sub { ...
```

becomes (if the callback is only called once):

```
   do_sth cb => Coro::rouse_cb;
   my @res = Coro::rouse_wait;
```

Your only other option is to use a state machine, e.g. using an object (there are many ways to implement state machines, especially in Perl):

```
my $state = new MyObject;

do_something callback => sub { $state->first_step_done };
```

And in first_step done, you register a callback for $self->next_state_done etc.

You can also look into some cpan modules, such as AnyEvent::Blackboard or AnyEvent::Tools - I haven't used them myself, but maybe they can help you.

As for condvars, I am personally not so hot about using them as the only means for an API - I prefer callbacks (as condvars are valid callbacks this allows both), but condvars do allow you to raise exceptions in the consumer (via the croak method).

Comment: Thanks for clarification. This leaves me with even more questions than I had initially, but at least now I can go and read myself.

Answer (score 3):

Well, one thing I can think of is using slightly modified Chain of Responsibility pattern:

```
my $params = {
  user => $user,
  event => $event,
  session => undef
};

my @chain = ('get_session', 'do_stuff', 'save_session', 'emit');

for my $index (0..$#chain) {
  my $current = $chain[$index];
  my $next    = $chain[$index + 1] || undef;
  $self->{$current}($params, 
    on_error => sub { $self->error($params) },
    on_success => sub { $self->{$next}($params) },
  );
}
```

It's a bit rough, but I hope it shows the point. )

Answer (score 1):

Visiting this question 7 years later, I seem to know the right answer: [monad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)). Coroutines, Future, Promise, async/await, and (a sane implementation of) a finite state machine are all subtypes of that.

Of course, [the curse of the monad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19544794/what-is-crockfords-law) prevents me from explaining it to others.

If I had to do it again today, I would've gone with some sort of promise objects.

Comment: "*some sort of promise objects*" is exactly what `Future` provides.

Comment: @melpomene yes, and I changed the selected answer based on that ground. Although I'm not working on the project I was asking this for, 7 years is a ton of time.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you had changed they accepted answer.